# Why hasn't Bitlocker recovery key been uploaded to Microsoft account if I am the Administrator

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, user-accounts, bitlocker, microsoft

Basically, I inherited my mom's HP laptop in 2022. I created a MS account for myself, gave myself administrator rights, and deleted her old account.

Fast-forwarding, I was prompted to upgrade the OS from Windows 10 to 11 for free. After a successful restart, I played in the new OS for a while before being prompted for more updates, which I agreed to.

Now, I am locked out of my own system. BitLocker is requiring the recovery key.

In my MS account, on another machine, I find the laptop listed among my other devices with serial number. However, under "manage recovery keys" no keys have been uploaded.

Can someone provide me with a reason why no recovery keys were uploaded if the account was mine (local or not I don't recall), with admin privileges (domain user or not I don't recall)?

Since the C: drive is scrambled, is there any way to locate the email address my mom (or someone at Staples) used to initially login to the Windows 10 in the recovery drive X: or in the BIOS? Tricks like {net user}, {wmic useraccount list full}, and {whoami /upn} obviously do not provide me with any useful information.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: If the account is already deleted then any methods I know to determine what email was user cannot be used, besides you can’t even boot into Windows, due to BitLocker asking for the recovery key.  As for the reason, you have indicate that process, probably would have been smart to disable BitLocker protection and enable it under your new account.

Comment: Had I known the problem it would have caused, I certainly would have disabled Bitlocker. It's a shame I wasn't prompted, "Update will trigger Bitlocker encryption, continue?"

Comment: "If the account is already deleted then any methods I know to determine what email was user cannot be used" Well I'm not so sure, because I had installed some software under my new account and noted that my mom's user name showed up at some point in the installation. I don't recall what that was. So the owner's name was still showing up in my account.

Comment: They update didn't enable BitLocker.  BitLocker was already enabled.  What caused the configuration change is not clear.  A Windows Update would not typically be enough to trigger, requesting the recovery key, which is a BItLocker security mechanism.

Comment: Like I wrote, the OS successfully upgraded to Win11, then after a short while I was able to initiate some updates in the Win11 environment which must have triggered Bitlocker. It wasn't my fault :) And had I known that Bitlocker was enabled I certainly would have made sure the key was uploaded to my account. Question remains: why hadn't the key made it to my account?

Comment: BitLocker does not just activate automatically.

Comment: Thank you :) I know that updates don't enable Bitlocker and I  know that Bitlocker doesn't activate automatically, but Bitlocker will lock you out of your system when you least expect it (like during an update) :)

Comment: Only system configuration changes would result in the prompt you are getting for the BitLocker recovery key, an update distributed via Windows Update, would not result in this particular prompt.

Comment: @Ramhound Not true. Search for Windows updates KB5012170 or  KB4535680 which have triggered Bitlocker recovery!

Comment: Neither of those updates should prompt for the BitLocker Recovery key on the type of hardware your talking about, unless the device, wasn’t fully updated and was lacking a SSU. Those are the exception to the rule